# Add extra space to all pages of a PDF file

Tags: pdf

When working with xournal on pdf files, i would like to have extra space on the sides of the pages, for some annotations.

How can i expand the pages ?
I am not looking for solutions in xournal exclusively, because i doubt that there is such functionality built in.

I did not find any solutions with google.

Comment: I wonder whether it should be possible with xournal  to write to PDF files?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your comment, but i edited my question, to make it clear, that the necessary step does not have to take place in xournal directly.

Answer (score 0):

What I have found is an instruction which seems to work with Adobe Acrobat XI Professional:

https://answers.acrobatusers.com/I-need-to-add-an-inch-of-white-space-at-the-top-of-a-document-and-I-can-t-figure-out-how-to-do-it-When-I-try-to-q219172.aspx

But this program is not free.